# Backbone - Chrome debug function called from trigger

Tags: javascript, debugging, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools

Backbone allows you to trigger functions in other classes - if you use correctly the Backbone.Events.

```
a.js
MyApp.vent.on("some:trigger", function(){
 // ...
});

b.js
function test(){
    doSomething();       
    MyApp.vent.trigger("some:trigger");
}
```

Do you know some way of reaching the function "some:trigger" after debug the doSomething() ? (Without having to find it in the code and putting a breakpoint on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [blackbox](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) the Backbone code. Then when you step into `MyApp.vent.trigger("some:trigger")` Chrome will skip all the Backbone code and go straight to your handler code.

The documentation linked above overcomplicates things a bit. All you have to do is right-click on the Backbone file in the source viewer and select "Blackbox Script". Then step into the `trigger` call.

[image: blackboxing backbone]

Comment: Exactly what I've looked for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of [Debugging JavaScript by Redefining Functions](https://gideonpyzer.com/blog/debugging-javascript-by-redefining-functions/). This essentially means overwriting the original function, injecting a `debugger` statement, and then calling the original function afterwards to continue the normal execution.

### Example

I have used a named function instead of an anonymous so that I can refer to it later.

```
MyApp.event.on("some:trigger", myFunc);
```

Now I can store a copy of the original function to call after debugging.

```
var oldFunc = myFunc;

myFunc = function() {
    debugger; // or use console.log()
    return oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This can be called in the Console or Snippet so that the next time you play through your code, it will break (or log output in the case of a `console.log` statement).

### Benefits

The benefit of this is that it doesn't matter how many places in the code the trigger handler get executed, or how many times, it will always break. You don't have to step through all the previous code using the debugger controls. For a single case, stepping through would be sufficient.

Comment: I'm a little afraid of this solution, because it opens an space to go to production :\

Comment: @GabrielSantosCarvalho You don't make these changes in your code. You just run the overwriting in the Console/Snippet when you want in real time. It's great when you have your handler called in many places as you don't need to step through all the time. If you only have one reference to your handler, then this is overkill and stepping through makes sense. It depends on your situation.